# Why is the SqlDependency object unable to detect the changes in SQL Server table?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, c#-4.0, sqldependency

It's been 3 days that I have been trying to achieve this but couldn't.

I am using the `SqlTableDependency` nuget package to get notifications if a particular table's cell gets modified. I have enabled the service broker.

I have taken every necessary measure. Upon starting the application it creates a trigger, queue, contract, message type automatically on the table and safely disposes upon closing the app but it never returns the results. The database user has `Db_Owner` role and everything but still not working. Please help me. I am frustrated and tired of this. It's been 3 days.

I change the values in the edit mode of the table or using an update query.

I am following this link. It has all the necessary steps and also a demo video.
https://github.com/christiandelbianco/monitor-table-change-with-sqltabledependency

Code:

```
namespace SqlDependency
{
    class Users
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        const string ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=HimHer; Integrated Security=True";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using(var dep = new SqlTableDependency<Users>(ConnectionString) )
            {
                dep.OnChanged += Dep_OnChanged;

                dep.Start();

                Console.WriteLine("Press a key to exit");
                Console.ReadKey();

                dep.Stop();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Waiting For Changes ..... ");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void Dep_OnChanged(object sender, RecordChangedEventArgs<Users> e)
        {
            var changedEntity = e.Entity;

            Console.WriteLine("DML operation: " + e.ChangeType);
            Console.WriteLine("ID: " + changedEntity.UserName);
            Console.WriteLine("Name: " + changedEntity.Password);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you ask this a few hours ago? anyway its obvious you are using the example on the nuget project site. this has to be a configuration issue. i think you are best (and would get a faster response) by asking directly on github

Comment: yes but that was with SQLDependency not SQLTABLEDEPENDENCY

Comment: Did you read through this notice and check your database compatibility level? https://github.com/christiandelbianco/monitor-table-change-with-sqltabledependency#-note-about-compatibility-level-and-database-version-for-tracking-record-changes

Comment: Done.

It was only because I haven't been using **sa** as a login. Only I changed my database to **sa** and used that in the connection string. It worked.